# Image not displaying in Simulator when setting it in the UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to build a Cocoa Touch Class that is assigned to my Navigation Controller in my Storyboard to display an image in the Navigation Bar in the center. The app builds but the image is not displayed and I can figure out why.

I am trying to build a Cocoa Touch Class that is assigned to my Navigation Controller in my Storyboard to display an image in the Navigation Bar in the center. The app builds but the image is not displayed and I can figure out why.

```
class NavBarImg: UINavigationController {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView()
    {
        if navigationController == nil{
        return
    }

    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BarTabsNavLogoWhite")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

    let bannerWidth = navigationBar.frame.size.width
    let bannerHeight = navigationBar.frame.size.height

    let bannerX = bannerWidth / 2 - image.size.width / 2
    let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - image.size.height / 2

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView  

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code in setupView or where ???

Comment: What is the size of your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation controller will not display its own navigation item, so the image will not be displayed simply by setting self.navigationItem.titleView to be the imageView you created.

Either set navigationItem.titleView to be the imageView you created on the view controller which is being displayed by the navigation controller or add the imageView as a subview to your navigation controller's navigation bar.

The latter can be done as follows:

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNavigationBar()
    }

    func setupNavigationBar() {
        let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BarTabsNavLogoWhite")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = navigationBar.frame
        navigationBar.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```